# Divide into view - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For example I want divide the result(this is number **INT**) of this in view:

```
@Model.Visits.Sum(i => i.TotalVisit)
```

for the number **60** for example.

Can it be divided in some way in the view? and how is the syntax?

Comment: Have you tried using the division operator?:  `/`

Comment: `@(Model.Visits.Sum(i => i.TotalVisit) / 60)`?  or `@Model.Visits.Sum(i => i.TotalVisit / 60)`?

Comment: thnks Amy, I worked  -> @(Model.Visits.Sum(i => i.TotalVisit) / 60) , I was wrongly placing the first (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do simple calculation on the razor view.

> Division is is @(@Model.Visits.Sum(i => i.TotalVisit) / b)

[Source](http://techfunda.com/howto/75/mathematical-operation-in-razor-view)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use operators in Razor views. Just like Iman showed.

`@(Model.Visits.Sum(i => i)/60)`

It's important to keep track of your parentheses. Here's a useful link regarding Razor views. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

Comment: Thnks Petter Pettersson.